Constant volatge at the output of LM311
I  made a PCB based on the following schematic.
The inputs of the comparator work as expected (i.e., the capacitor voltage or the voltage at the non-inverting pin gradually increases and, after a few seconds, becomes greater than the threshold voltage at the inverting input). I expected the output of the comparator to change when the capacitor voltage exceeded the threshold voltage. However, I am reading a constant voltage of around 0.8 volts at pin 7 using digital multimeter.
The Vcc voltage is 5 volts.

Thanks for suggestions. I made two boards, and both worked the same. Therefore, I thought it's rare that both comparators have been damaged. But today I replace both LM311 with new ones and see that the circuit works as I expected.

Just to confirm: you found that you had two separate LM311 that did not work "out of the box"?  If that is the case, then you may have found a bad batch.

There is something wrong with your circuit, it does not match the schematic you've provided- maybe the LM311 is something else or  the connections are not what you think.
For example, the output voltage is several times too high for an LM311 with output low and sinking 5mA. It's also a suspicious voltage value which suggests something else is going on, other than just a fried chip.

Check your R6 (or is it R5, your schematic is hard to read?), is it really 1kΩ, or is it perhaps 100Ω?  The output voltage of 0.8V is more in line with R5 being 100Ω, not 1kΩ.  However, even if R5 is the wrong value, I am at a loss to explain why the output did not change when expected.  Perhaps your real-world circuit does not match the schematic, or your chip is damaged.
One possible explanation: inside the LM311, R13 is open-circuit.  Referring to the datasheet from ST (image below), R13 sets the output current limit.  If it is much higher than its nominal value of 4Ω, then Q15 emitter voltage cannot go below Vbe of Q16, which is about 0.7V, which aligns with what you are measuring.  This fault can only happen if the chip was faulty to start with, or has been damaged.

Link for above image:  page 3/14 of this URL:
https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lm211.pdf
So in summary:

Check R6 is correct.
Check your PCB matches your schematic.
Check your power supply voltage.
Replace the LM311 with a known good unit.

